# Top menu CSS design

Tags: css, user-interface, menu

I'm trying to have a top menu bar but I fail using `float: left`. How to have the correct behaviour (mentionned here in the widget itself) for a **top menu bar** ?

```css
      * { margin:0; padding: 0; }
      #menu { background-color: yellow; }
      #left {background-color: green; width: 200px; }
      #mid { background-color: red; width: 40%; float: left; }
      #right {background-color: blue; float: left; }
```

```html
   <div id="menu">
     <div id="left">left green: 200px</div> 
     <div id="mid">mid red: 40% of browser width</div> 
     <div id="right">right blue: rest</div>
   </div>
   <div>
     content of the site
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do. I used CSS `flexbox` which makes it fairly easy.

```css
      * { margin:0; padding: 0; }
      #menu { background-color: yellow; display: flex; }
      #left {background-color: green; flex: 0 0 200px; }
      #mid { background-color: red; flex: 0 0 40%; }
      #right {background-color: blue; flex: 1; }
```

```html
   <div id="menu">
     <div id="left">left green: 200px</div> 
     <div id="mid">mid red: 40% of browser width</div> 
     <div id="right">right blue: rest</div>
   </div>
   <div>
     content of the site
    </div>
```

If you need legacy support, then you just need to apply the floats properly:

```css
      * { margin:0; padding: 0; }
      #menu { background-color: yellow; }
      #left {background-color: green; float: left; width: 200px; }
      #mid { background-color: red; float: left; width: 40%; }
      #right {background-color: blue; }
```

```html
   <div id="menu">
     <div id="left">left green: 200px</div> 
     <div id="mid">mid red: 40% of browser width</div> 
     <div id="right">right blue: rest</div>
   </div>
   <div>
     content of the site
    </div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for that clarification. Appreciate your time and effort in ensuring accurate answers.

Comment: @Quantastical The strange thing is that `flex` is badly supported on ... Chrome & Safari for iPad (even the recent versions). For example here is a problem I get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877321/display-flex-doesnt-work-on-ipad-both-chrome-and-safari  Do you have any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: @Basj, `flex` is supported in iOS Safari back to version 7, but requires vendor prefixes for some. Did you add `-webkit-flex` (and the other vender-specific properties) as well?

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that.

It's important to use the correct flex properties so that the limited width divs do not expand.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
}
#left {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
#mid {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 40%;
}
#right {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="left">left green: 200px</div>
  <div id="mid">mid red: 40% of browser width</div>
  <div id="right">right blue: rest</div>
</div>
<div>
  content of the site
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! Never heard of flex before! How did people do before flex? (I think for example bootstrap doesn't use flex).

Comment: @Basj Bootstrap 4 is moving to flex IIRC. Previously, they were doing floats.

Comment: I tried on iPad and it seems that `flex` is not well supported on Chrome & Safari for iPad (even the recent versions). Your code doesn't render very on such devices. I created a question for this if maybe you have an idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877321/display-flex-doesnt-work-on-ipad-both-chrome-and-safari

Comment: I haven't prefixed this and Safari / iOS does require that so you'd have to adapt. - http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox So Safari does support flexbox and has done for several versions.