# display: flex; doesn't work on iPad (both Chrome and Safari)

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, flexbox

This code works as expected on computer but **totally fails to render the `display: flex` on both Chrome 47 for iPad and Safari for iPad** (in landscape view, width 1024px).

It's strange because `flex` should be well supported on Chrome since a long time.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#header { height: 60px; display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; }
#topleft { flex: 0 0 155px; height: 100%; background-color: green; }
#topmid { flex: 0 0 40%; height: 100%; background-color: blue; }
#topright { flex: 1; background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="topleft">Topleft</div>
  <div id="topmid">Topmid</div>
  <div id="topright">Topright</div>
</div>
```

**What's wrong?**

Comment: Waw... The more I test examples with `flex`, the more I see examples that fail. Example: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/qazmI isn't rendered correctly at all on iPad mini with Chrome 47.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your iPad isn't running iOS 9, you need to add `-webkit-flex: 0 0 155px;` to #topleft, `-webkit-flex: 0 0 40%;` to #topmid, and `-webkit-flex: 1;` to #topright.

Making an assumption based on your inclusion of `display: -webkit-flex;`

So, your new CSS might look like:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#header { height: 60px; display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; }
#topleft { -webkit-flex: 0 0 155px; flex: 0 0 155px; height: 100%; background-color: green; }
#topmid { -webkit-flex: 0 0 40%; flex: 0 0 40%; height: 100%; background-color: blue; }
#topright { -webkit-flex: 1; flex: 1; background-color: yellow; }
```

Also, Chrome on iPad is still using the Safari engine... it's just a webview, so we don't get all the up to date Chrome goodness we get on android devices.